# Does the series $\sum n!/(n+2)!$ diverge or converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm somewhat stuck to prove the convergence status of $\sum$$n!/(n+2)!$

I tried using the Ratio test, but ended up with $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{n+3} = 1$, which makes the test inconclusive.

From WolframAlpha I already found out the series is converging, but what's the way forward to prove this.
I was thinking of either Comparison Test or Limit Comparison Test, but what to use as comparison series?

Comment: Hint:  the terms simplify to $\frac 1{(n+1)(n+2)}$.

Comment: simplify $n!/(n+2)!$ (there's a lot of cancellation).

Comment: Even lower-tech than comparison, you can simplify as in the earlier comments, then use the elementary identity $\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}$ to evaluate the telescoping sum.

Comment: It just converges, the denominator is just way larger than the nominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just note that
$$
\dfrac{n!}{(n+2)!}=\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
$$

and compare with $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{n!}{(n+2)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left( \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{N+2} \right)$$
$$\implies S_{\infty}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers use the two nicest approaches available, comparison and telescoping. They deserve to be contrasted with an "overkill" alternative. If the sum starts at $n=0$, it's$$\int_0^\infty\left(\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{x^n}{(n+2)!}\right)e^{-x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2e^x}dx.$$The integrand is asymptotic to $\frac12$ if $0<x\ll1$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ if $x\gg1$, so the integral converges.

Comment: Nice approach but one question. how do you get from convergence of the integral to finiteness of the summation?

Comment: @Thomas I think you're asking how we know the integral matches the sum, i.e. why the $\int$ commutes with the $\Sigma$.The [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) should prove as much.